# SimpleInjector.GetAllInstances throwing unexpected error

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

I have the following method which raises a domain event. An instance of an `IDomainEvent` is passed to the method and it is handled using instances of `IDomainEventHandler` supplied by SimpleInjector's `GetAllInstances` method.

The method looks like this:

```
public static void Raise<T>(T domainEvent) where T : IDomainEvent
{
    if (Container != null)
    {
        var handlerType =
            typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>).MakeGenericType(domainEvent.GetType());

        var handlers = Container.GetAllInstances(handlerType);

        foreach (dynamic handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.Handle((dynamic)domainEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

`Container` is supplied previously in the class that contains this method, but it is an instance of a SimpleInjector `IContainer`.

An example `IDomainEventHandler` for a `NewOrderEvent` looks like:

```
 public class NewOrderEventHandler : IDomainEventHandler<NewOrderEvent>
 {
    public void Handle(NewOrderEvent args)
    {
        // Event handled here.
    }
 }
```

And a sample `IDomainEvent` looks like:

```
public class NewOrderEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    public IOrder Order { get; set; }
}
```

The `IDomainEventHandler<>` is registered with SimpleInjector as such:

```
var assemblies = new[] {
            // Other assemblies use this too
            typeof(NewOrderEventHandler).Assembly, // Event Handlers
        };

container.Register(typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>), assemblies);
```

When I run the method, I get the following exception:

> No registration for type
>   `IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<NewOrderEvent>>` could be found. There
>   is, however, a registration for `IDomainEventHandler<NewOrderEvent>`;
>   Did you mean to call `GetInstance<IDomainEventHandler<NewOrderEvent>>()`
>   or depend on `IDomainEventHandler<NewOrderEvent>`?

I don't quite understand why this isn't working - can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like you are using `Register` instead of `RegisterCollection`: please show the code that registers the `IDomainEventHandler`'s

Comment: @qujck OP have it here `container.Register(typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>), assemblies);` I think you're right. RegisterCollection should help.

Comment: @qujck That was the issue (the registration code is above).  If you post an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error leads me to believe you are using `Register` instead of `RegisterCollection`: items registered with `Register` are resolved with `GetInstance`, items registered with `RegisterCollection` are resolved with `GetAllInstances`.